# How to find the direction of acceleration if an object is changing its direction of velocity but not magnitude then how we can find the direction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, kinematics, acceleration, velocity

I am new at this topic so please do mind if my question doest make sense to you.I am trying to find out that what will be the direction of acceleration if object changes Direction of velocity but not magnitude
I know little about circular motion is that acceleration is always perpendicular to velocity

But there can also case exist when acceleration is not only perpendicular to velocity

(Case such as - object moving along x direction and suddenly changes it path in y direction in time interval 't' then what will be acceleration and Direction and magnitude of acceleration)

If there is no such case possible please explain to me

Thank you for your precious time you given to my doubt

Answer (score 0):

If velocity keeps the same magnitude at all times, then:
$$\lVert\vec{v}\rVert=\text{cst}
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
\vec{v}.\vec{v}=\text{cst}$$
Derive this expression with respect to time:
$$\vec{v}.\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}=0
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
\vec{v}.\vec{a}=0$$
In other words, acceleration has to be perpendicular to velocity in this case.

You can interpret this the following way:

- the component of acceleration alongside the direction of velocity will change the velocity's magnitude without changing its direction;
- the component of acceleration perpendicular to velocity will change the velocity's direction without changing its magnitude.

Note that acceleration being perpendicular to velocity doesn't give you any information about the trajectory's shape, only that motion is uniform. The uniform circular motion is just the most basic example.

Comment: Can you explain the cases
 which u mentioned in my doubt for x and y direction what will the direction at that time

Comment: I'm sorry, can you rephrase the question? I'm not sure I understand. The example you mention seems to be completely covered by my answer (the acceleration suddenly gets a non-zero component perpendicular to velocity, making the trajectory bend).

Comment: The question I asked was suppose a particle moving in x direction with Velocity V and changes its direction to Y axis then what will be the direction of acceleration

Comment: I thought it as suppose a particle moving in x direction with Velocity 'v' and changes it direction to y but magnitude remains same then  a = vj-vi/t is the value which is at an angle of 45 degree from the original velocity vector at the time when they are changing direction

Comment: And also I want to point out that you mentioned acceleration must be perpendicular to velocity for that case , and we know that acceleration is produced by force , so from where the force is coming which is producing direction perpendicular the velocity vector

Comment: My answer is a general result, saying how acceleration must be for velocity to keep a constant magnitude. After that, you can use it for any example of your choice. No matter what forces there are, if the total force is perpendicular to velocity, then velocity's magnitude will be constant.